# Matrix of expected values from matrix of observed using a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to figure out how to use a for loop to create a matrix of expected values. it should be able to handle a matrix of any size. This is all I've been able to come up with so far.

```
for(i in 1:obsv){
   for(j in 1:obsv){
      obsv[i,j]<-(sum(obsv[i,])*sum(obsv[,j]))/sum(obsv)
  }
}
##obsv is the name of the matrix of observed values
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is obviously wrong, see below. The main error was that you need to loop through `1:nrow(obsv)` and `1:ncol(obsv)`, not like you are doing it.
I will use a fake matrix, since you haven't posted an example dataset.

```
obsv <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)

obsv2 <- obsv    # modify a copy

for(i in 1:nrow(obsv)){
   for(j in 1:ncol(obsv)){
      obsv2[i, j] <- sum(obsv[i, ])*sum(obsv[, j])/sum(obsv)
  }
}
```

Now, the above code can be greatly simplified. A one-liner will do it.

```
obsv3 <- rowSums(obsv) %*% t(colSums(obsv))/sum(obsv)

identical(obsv2, obsv3)
#[1] TRUE
```